# Github Actions: missing telegram token or user list

Tags: telegram, github-actions

I'm trying to use Github Actions to send a Telegram message every time someone pushes to the master of repo. But using [this action](https://github.com/appleboy/telegram-action) causes the following error and action fails:

`missing telegram token or user list`

Here is my yml file:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Telegram Notify
        uses: appleboy/telegram-action@0.0.3
        with:
          to: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID }}
          token: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_TOKEN }}
          message: |
            An event occured in ${{ github.repository    }} repository.
            ${{ github.event_name }}
```

I quite new in Github Actions. What should I do to fix this?

P.S: I've added telegram_token and telegram_chat_id to secrets section of repo.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, who got error "missing telegram token or user list" on "appleboy/telegram-action" when using reusability workflow (or workflow_call), may this help.

If you are using workflow reusability to use send telegram notif,
for example:

```
# .github/workflows/send-telegram.yml
name: Send Telegram Notification

on: [workflow_call]
jobs:
  send-notif:
    name: Send Telegram Notification
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: send telegram message on push
        uses: appleboy/telegram-action@master
        with:
          to: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID }}
          token: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_TOKEN }}
          message: |
            ${{ github.actor }} created commit:
            Commit message: ${{ github.event.commits[0].message }}

            Repository: ${{ github.repository }}

            See changes: https://github.com/${{ github.repository }}/commit/${{github.sha}}
```

secrets wont get passed directly to here!

you need to pass it on your caller like this

```
# .github/workflows/testing-tele-notif.yml
name: Testing telegram notification

on:
  push:
    branches: [test/telegram-notif]
  pull_request:
    branches: [test/telegram-notif]

jobs:
  send-notif-on-success:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/send-telegram.yml
    secrets: inherit # MUST PUT THIS!

  send-notif-on-failure:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/send-telegram.yml
    secrets: inherit # MUST PUT THIS!
```

Hence, on your workflow_call will use the secrets provided by the caller.

I hope somene who stumble on the same problem

Answer (score -1):

Go to the repo settings and set the secrets for the TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID and the TELEGRAM_TOKEN. when setting the secrets for TELEGRAM_TOKEN make sure to send the queries to the Telegram Bot API using the bot token https://api.telegram.org/bot/METHOD_NAME, for example https://api.telegram.org/bot19023205:BNF-23dred1234ghIkl-dre4fdgr8nv1w4od/getMe